# xsl:for-each, then xsl:value for same element?

Tags: xml, xslt

Can I pull the value of elements after I call them using for-each.

Input

```
        <draft_mac_data>
      <maintenance_function justification="center">Setup</maintenance_function>
      <maintenance_level_c justification="center">10.00</maintenance_level_c>
      <tools_test_equipment_codes>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>42</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>48</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>49</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>78</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>100</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>101</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>114</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>117</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>124</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>128</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>151</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>165</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>169</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>176</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>177</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>196</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
        <tools_test_equipment_reference_code>235</tools_test_equipment_reference_code>
      </tools_test_equipment_codes>
    </draft_mac_data>
```

XSLT clip:

```
<qualify-2lvl>
                        <maintfunc><xsl:attribute name="func"><xsl:value-of select="doc:maintenance_function"/></xsl:attribute></maintfunc>
                        <xsl:for-each select="doc:maintenance_level_c">
                            <maintclass-2lvl>
                                <c><xsl:value-of select="doc:maintenance_level_c"/></c>
                            </maintclass-2lvl>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="doc:maintenance_level_f">
                            <maintclass-2lvl>
                                <f><xsl:value-of select="doc:maintenance_level_f"/></f>
                            </maintclass-2lvl>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="doc:maintenance_level_h">
                            <maintclass-2lvl>
                                <h><xsl:value-of select="doc:maintenance_level_h"/></h>
                            </maintclass-2lvl>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="doc:maintenance_level_d">
                            <maintclass-2lvl>
                                <d><xsl:value-of select="doc:maintenance_level_d"/></d>
                            </maintclass-2lvl>
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                        <xsl:for-each select="doc:tools_test_equipment_codes/doc:tools_test_equipment_reference_code">
                            <trefs>
                            <tref><xsl:attribute name="refs"><xsl:value-of select="concat('teref', doc:tools_test_equipment_reference_code)"/></xsl:attribute></tref>
                            </trefs>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                </qualify-2lvl>
```

Output

```
        <qualify-2lvl>
      <maintfunc func="Load / Unload"/>
      <maintclass-2lvl>
        <c/>
      </maintclass-2lvl>
      <trefs>
        <tref refs="teref"/>
      </trefs>
      <trefs>
        <tref refs="teref"/>
      </trefs>
      <trefs>
        <tref refs="teref"/>
      </trefs>
      <trefs>
        <tref refs="teref"/>
      </trefs>
      <trefs>
        <tref refs="teref"/>
      </trefs>
    </qualify-2lvl>
```

for instance. I am trying to say for each of the ***tools_test_equipment_reference_code elements***, create
 and populate the ***refs*** attribute with the value of ***tools_test_equipment_reference_code elements***.

Is there a more precise way of doing this? am I missing something?

Comment: So what would be the desired output instead, and whats the issue with current transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the `xsl:for-each select="doc:maintenance_level_c"` the context node is that element so to output its value use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.